# how not send ajax call when offline?

Tags: ajax

if user play with my site offline and site must send some ajax how do i know that there is no internet so that not to send ajax calls?

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/offline.html

but works only in bleeding edge browsers

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for you: http://html5demos.com/offline

Only works on latest versions for FireFox and Opera ATM.  IE9 should support it however you can extend the above to support current version of IE by using this as a backup: http://html5demos.com/nav-online